# PHP Custom sort by specific variable

Tags: php, sorting

Good day,
The following code works as expected and gives the desired result:

```
                $f = 'Focus' . ' : ' .  $jobdemand_F . ' - ' . $foil_F_answer;
                $o = 'Organisation' . ' : ' .  $jobdemand_O . ' - ' . $foil_O_answer;
                $i = 'Interaction' . ' : ' .  $jobdemand_I . ' - ' . $foil_I_answer;
                $l = 'Load' . ' : ' .  $jobdemand_L . ' - ' . $foil_L_answer;

                $foilorder=array($f, $o, $i, $l);
                sort($foilorder);

                $arrlength=count($foilorder);
                for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
                  {
                  echo $foilorder[$x];
                  echo "<br>";
                  }
```

The output is :

```
Focus : 2 - Below average

Interaction : 4 - Average

Load : 3 - Average

Organisation : 1 - Average
```

I want to sort this on the second variable:
eg. `$jobdemand_F`

So that the output becomes

```
Organisation : 1 - Average

Focus : 2 - Below average

Load : 3 - Average

Interaction : 4 - Average
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `usort`:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
 $anumber = substr($a, strpos($a, ": ") + 1);
 $anumber = substr($anumber , 1, 1);
 $bnumber = substr($b, strpos($b, ": ") + 1);
 $bnumber = substr($bnumber , 1, 1);

if ($anumber == $bnumber) {
    return 0;
}
return ($anumber < $bnumber) ? -1 : 1;
}


// sort
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) instead of `sort` function to sort the values by user-defined comparison.

Use [sanitize filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) - `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` to fetch the number from the string:

```
usort($foilorder, function($a, $b) {
    $a = (int)filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $b = (int)filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

---

**Note:** Instead, you can sort before building the string. Say you can declare the variables as associative array and then sort them, build it into desired string. That reduce these complexities decreasing the code lines too.